# How do I create tabs in Pug

Tags: express, pug

I have a Node/Express app in Visual Studio and I want to create tabs, so when you click on a tab, it displays the content below. The thing is, I'm using an HTML-->Pug converter (I'm very new to Pug), so I would not be surprised if something went afoul in there. Below is my code, but nothing is showing and when I click a tab, it only changes color slightly (shown in the Tokyo tab), but does not show any content.

[image]

Here's what I have so far in my `index.pug`:

```
extends layout

    block content
      doctype html
      html(lang="en")
        head
          meta(charset='utf-8')
          meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        section
          nav
            ul
              li.title Study Bot
              li.robot 
                img(src='/images/robot-face.jpg' alt='Robot face' width='130px')
          article
        footer
          // Tab links
          .tab
            button.tablinks(onclick="openCity(event, 'London')") London
            button.tablinks(onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')") Paris
            button.tablinks(onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')") Tokyo
          // Tab content
          #London.tabcontent
            h3 London
            p London is the capital city of England.
          #Paris.tabcontent
            h3 Paris
            p Paris is the capital of France.
          #Tokyo.tabcontent
            iframe#encyclopedia-window(src='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/')
```

In my `main.css` (the relevant parts):

```
footer {
    background-color: #666;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: white;
}
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;initial-letter
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}

#encyclopedia-window {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25px;
    height: 90%;
    width: 95%;
}
```

Also this in my `index.js`:

```
/* Clickable tabs */
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Comment: Try to use tabcontent ID in lowercase: `#london.tabcontent` instead of `London.tabcontent`. And look at [bootstrap tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs), don't create a bicycle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this was due to a simple typographical error ("London" vs. "london")

Comment: The change in case did not work, but I'm looking into the Bootstrap way, thanks. @alexmac

Answer (score 0):

It was surprisingly simple. I only needed to include a reference to my script in the `index.js` file at the end of my `index.pug` file, where I need to call the function used in that section.

So I added:

```
script
  include ../routes/index.js
```

Here it is in context of the `index.pug` file:

```
extends layout

block content

  doctype html
  html(lang="en")
    head
      meta(charset='utf-8')
      meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    section
      nav
        ul
          li.title Study Bot
          li.robot 
            img(src='/images/robot-face.jpg' alt='Robot face' width='130px')
      article
    footer
      // Tab links
      .tab
        button.tablinks(onclick="openCity(event, 'London')") London
        button.tablinks(onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')") Paris
        button.tablinks(onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')") Tokyo
      // Tab content
      #London.tabcontent
        h3 London
        p London is the capital city of England.
      #Paris.tabcontent
        h3 Paris
        p Paris is the capital of France.
      #Tokyo.tabcontent
        iframe#encyclopedia-window(src='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/')
      script
        include ../routes/index.js
```